# In Conky, how can I calculate the time elapsed since a specific date?

Tags: conky, lua

In conky, I would like to display the number of days since a specific date. For this, I would substract the current date from the said specific date.

E.g.: If I were to set `ImportantDate = 2016-09-25`
Then, using something like:

`${time %d %B}` *minus* `ImportantDate` ...

... on 2016-09-27, conky would display "2"; and "3" the next day, etc.

I did not find any example of date manipulation in the conky scripts that I could adapt. Does anyone have an idea?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can execute external commands from within Conky. For example I have this one:

```
${execpi .001 (awk '{printf "%s/", $1}' /proc/loadavg; grep -c processor /proc/cpuinfo;) | bc -l | cut -c1-4}
```

It takes the CPU load average and divides it by the number of CPU's limiting the results to 3 decimal places.

You can write the bulk of your date arithmetic in a bash script (or another program) and call it from conky.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't thought of creating a separate bash script. Will do!

Comment: My pleasure. Can you mark answer as solution so your quesrion comes off the unanswered list?

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I think I can use the information posted on this website (http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/timedate.html) to manipulate dates in a bash script, and proceed as WinEunuuchs2Unix proposed.